# How do I edit and delete data in Django?

Tags: python, django, editing

I am using django 1.0 and I have created my models using the example in the Django book.  I am able to perform the basic function of adding data; now I need a way of retrieving that data, loading it into a form (change_form?! or something), **EDIT** it and save it back to the DB. Secondly how do I **DELETE** the data that's in the DB? i.e. search, select and then delete!

Please show me an example of the code I need to write on my `view.py` and `urls.py` for perform this task.

Answer (score 35):

Say you have a model Employee. To edit an entry with primary key emp_id you do:

```
emp = Employee.objects.get(pk = emp_id)
emp.name = 'Somename'
emp.save()
```

to delete it just do:

```
emp.delete()
```

so a full view would be:

```
def update(request, id):
   emp = Employee.objects.get(pk = id)
   #you can do this for as many fields as you like
   #here I asume you had a form with input like <input type="text" name="name"/>
   #so it's basically like that for all form fields
   emp.name = request.POST.get('name')
   emp.save()
   return HttpResponse('updated')

def delete(request, id):
   emp = Employee.objects.get(pk = id)
   emp.delete()
   return HttpResponse('deleted')
```

In urls.py you'd need two entries like this:

```
(r'^delete/(\d+)/$','myproject.myapp.views.delete'),
(r'^update/(\d+)/$','myproject.myapp.views.update'),
```

I suggest you take a look at the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs)

Comment: For those coming to this question at this point: Rather than going directly to `request.POST.get`, you'd definitely want to use `is_valid()`. [See django's docs on validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/)... it's pretty extensive and very well designed.

Answer (score 3):

To do either of these you need to use something called queries.

check link below for really great documentation on that!
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/)

To Delete Data:

```
b = ModelName.objects.get(id = 1)
b.delete()
```

This will delete the Object of the model w/ an ID of 1

To edit Data:

```
b = ModelName.objects.get(id = 1)
b.name = 'Henry'
b.save()
```

This will change the name of the Object of the model w/ an ID of 1 to be Henry

Answer (score -9):

Read the following: [The Django admin site](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#ref-contrib-admin).  Then revise your question with specific details.

Comment: this topic doesn't have anything to do with admin site. he is asking for model instance method (delete).

Comment: @israkir: The built-in Django admin site will allow a person to delete model instances and edit data.  That's what it does.  The topic says "loading it into a form (change_form?! or something), EDIT it and save it back to the DB."  That's what the admin site does.