# django delete() success function error

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

So Im having issues with my delete function, it does delete the object its meant to but wont go to window.location. Instead I get the error

DoesNotExist at /api/personnel/delete/
Resource matching query does not exist.

Which I imagine is because it has just been deleted. how do I get past this issue?

```
var deletepers = function(){    
var persid = getUrlVars()["id"];
data={persid}
console.log(persid);
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/personnel/delete/",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response){
                window.location.href = "/Personnel";
        }   
    })
}

def delete_personnel(request):

    # Try find the requested app
    if request.method == "POST":
    pers_id = request.POST.get('persid')

    pers = Resource.objects.get(id=pers_id)
    if not pers: return HttpResponseNotFound()

    pers.delete()

    return HttpResponse(content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Not related, but if you want your page to get refreshed, why do you use javascript to delete? Why don't you just use a normal view to do the delete?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311188/how-do-i-edit-and-delete-data-in-django?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

You aren't passing the data in the format that your view is expecting. `{persid}` in JS is interpreted just as `persid`, not a hash at all; so in the view, `request.POST.get('persid')` is None.

Instead use an actual JS hash:

```
data = { persid: persid }
```

Comment: Now I tried that to begin with and it wasn't working hence why my code is a wee bit muddled after changing a lot about trying to get it to work.